# How I solve Laravel guzzlehttp/guzzle version error

Tags: laravel, composer-php

When I run `composer require baileyherbert/envato`, it shows this error:

```
Problem 1
- Root composer.json requires baileyherbert/envato ^3.0.0 -> satisfiable by 
baileyherbert/envato[3.0.0].
- baileyherbert/envato 3.0.0 requires guzzlehttp/guzzle ^6.5.5 -> found 
guzzlehttp/guzzle[6.5.5, ..., 6.5.x-dev] but it conflicts with your root 
composer.json require (^7.5).

Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and 
removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.
```

How can I fix this? Thanks

Comment: do `composer update` first then `composer require baileyherbert/envato`

Comment: You can't install `baileyherbert/envato` because that pacakge requires `guzzlehttp/guzzle: ^6.0` but you have `^7.5`. Share your `composer.json` and tell us which laravel version you are using

Comment: my laravel version is ^8.0.2